# regex to replace values

Tags: node.js, regex, regex-group

Input:

`.city.playground[?(@.playhouse == 'true' && @.IsPoolAvailable=='true')].checked]`

Output:

`.city.poolavailable.checked`

Regex to convert input to output:

```
result = result.replace("playground[?(@.playhouse == 'true' && @.IsPoolAvailable=='true')]",'poolavailable');
```

This regex does not render the expected output. Please help with any other regex that can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *escape* the special characters in your regex. Use:

`playground\[\?\(@\.playhouse\s*==\s*'true'\s+&&\s+@\.IsPoolAvailable\s*==\s*'true'\)\](\.\S+)\]`

Then replace the match with `poolavailable$1`.

```
result = result.replace("playground\[\?\(@\.playhouse\s*==\s*'true'\s+&&\s+@\.IsPoolAvailable\s*==\s*'true'\)\](\.\S+)\]", "poolavailable$1");
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/We6sIy/3)

Comment: I understand special characters should be excaped-maybe I am missing something that is easily overlooked. I ran  result = result.replace(/\.playground\[\?\(@\.playhouse\s*==\s*'true'\s+&&\s+@\.IsPoolAvailable\s*==\s*'true'\)\]/g,'poolavailable'); in node and nothing changes in my input file.

Comment: after your updated answer can you verify if this is correct                                    result = result.replace('playground\[\?\(@\.playhouse\s*==\s*'true'\s+&&\s+@\.IsPoolAvailable\s*==\s*'true'\)\](\.\S+)\]','poolavailable');    I am also getting missing ) for argument list error.

Comment: You need to replace with `poolavailable$1`. Check the demo link. Also use the regex I gave in the answer, the one in the comment is wrong!

Comment: yes, I added the regex exactly from the demo with replacing match as poolavailable$1. It is something to do with how I am adding it in my query  result = result.replace('playground[\?(@\.playhouse\s*==\s*'true'\s+&&\s+@\.IsPoolAvailable\s*==\s*'true')](\.\S+)]','poolavailable$1')

Comment: You are copying it wrong. The demo has `playground\[` while you have `playground[` (see the escaped [). There are other mistakes too, so just copy paste. How hard can that be?

Comment: You have also missed escaping `(`, which appears to be the reason of the error you see.

Comment: result = result.replace(/\.playground\[\?\(@\.playhouse\s*==\s*'true'\s+&&\s+@\.IsPoolAvailable\s*==\s*'true'\)\](\.\S+)\] /g, poolavailable$1') I don't get the missing escaping ( but there is no change in my output file

Comment: You are still copying the regex wrong! I just added the `replace()` call in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regular expression:`playground\[\?\( @\.IsPoolAvailable=='true'\)\]`

Comment: Special characters need to be escaped

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                                
  result = result.replace('playground\[\?\( @\.IsPoolAvailable=='true'\)\]','checked'); it throws an error missing ) after argument list

Comment: Try this one:`result = result.replace("playground\[\?\( @\.IsPoolAvailable=='true'\)\]",'poolavailable');`

Comment: `.*+?^${}()|[]\` are special characters

Comment: I edited the question with the updated input and output. Also, I tried the above it still didnt work

Comment: Is this the result you want? [https://regex101.com/r/KmWMzm/1/](https://regex101.com/r/KmWMzm/1/)

Comment: expected result: .city.poolavailable.checked in the link it is showing .city.poolavailable.checked]      ']' is not required at the end of checked

Comment: If "checked" is stable. try :[https://regex101.com/r/KmWMzm/2/](https://regex101.com/r/KmWMzm/2/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197020/discussion-between-eva-and-oliver-hao).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the capture group to solve it.As follow:

```js
result.replace(/(\.city\.).*?(\.checked)\]/i,'$1poolavailable$2');
```

[click here to look at](https://regex101.com/r/7fLuUv/1)